# How to apply a function to each current active modal image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a modal and am trying to apply a specific function to each image independently of the other images. I've tried *getElementsByClassNames*, specifically trying to get the 'active' class and after many hours have discovered that isn't possible... I'm now deep in the weeds and am very confused by possible solutions, which seem to be accessing the *data-target*, or *data-id*.

Everything works when I pass one unique ID, but I am unable to get the function to read the current modal image.

This should be all the relevant html and script:

```
<HTML>



// modal//
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  tools();
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  //tools function with slideindex n//
}


function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
  {
    
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

//the start of the effect script, tried and failed to pass a unique id on active slide...//
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
  var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
  var imgID = $('#this').data('id');
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  result = document.getElementById(resultID);
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("DIV");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
~~~~~...}
<div class="modalIcon">
   <img src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1);" alt="info text" class="hover-item cursor">
</div>
       
<div class="modalIcon">
    <img src="imge2.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2);" class="hover-item cursor">
 </div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content" id="mod">
    <div class="mySlides">         
      <div class="modalImage">
        <img class="modimg"  id="mymodalimage" data-target="#modal" data-id="0" src="image1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="modalImage">
        <img class="modimg"  id="mymodalimage" data-target="#modal" data-id="1" src="image2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="imageEffect">
     <span class="effectbtn cursor" id="showzoombox" onclick="imageZoom('myimage', 'myresult')">z</span>
</div>




</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: can you edit the snippet and give us a working model

Comment: if you just need to get the active element have you tried document.activeElement.tagName;?

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work, i tried: img = document.activeElement(imgID);

Comment: I don't think that's right.  Try the following: console.log(document.activeElement.tagName) and tell me what you get. Be sure to have an active element, like focus on an input box. Remember, there's only one active element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what to put, at the moment the function is calling the tag from the HTML with 'imgID'. so img = document.activeElement(imgID);, are you saying it should be img = console.log(document.activeElement.imgID). I don't think that makes sense.

Comment: Console reads: Uncaught TypeError: img is undefined. But I knew I didn't really follow you.

Answer (score 0):

since there's only one active element you access it as follows:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', t, true); 

function t(){
console.log(document.activeElement.tagName)
console.log(document.activeElement.id)
console.log(document.activeElement.name)
console.log(document.activeElement)}
```

```html
<input name='test' id='save' />
```

Comment: I hear you but it's not working. I call the function via a separate button: onclick="imageZoom('myimage', 'myresult')", and the function runs: function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) { var img = document.activeElement(imgID); ...} I think the way the function is called and runs is throwing it off. I don't know I've been struggling for hours but I'm a newb.

Comment: There is only one active element. Var img=document.activeElement;

Comment: I solved it: I changed each image ID to include a number e.g. 'myimage1' etc, then when i called the id 'myimage' i also called the console.log of each slide number, which matched the ID number, and combined both of them to then getElementById. Thanks @DCR thanks for pointing me in the direction of the console log.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: I changed each image ID to include a number e.g. 'myimage1' etc, then when i called the id 'myimage' i also called the console.log of each slide number, which matched the ID number, and combined both of them to then getElementById. Thanks @DCR thanks for pointing me in the direction of the console log.